# using semicolon without any command in for loop in C

Tags: c

these codes do the same work. I don't understand why

```
for ( ; *s1 = *s2; s1++, s2++ ) { ;}
for ( ; *s1 = *s2; s1++, s2++ ) {*s1=*s2;}
```

Comment: Where does the iteration end?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin when `*s2 == 0`

Comment: It would have too. Anything other than a valid nul-terminated string in `s2` and the sky is the limit. (or the memory segment rather...)

Comment: @P__J__: Actually, it stops when `*s1` is zero after the assignment. `*s2` could still be non-zero. For example, it could be ½.

Comment: @EricPostpischil if *s1 is zero after the assignment *s2 is too as *s1 is assigned with *s2

Comment: @P__J__: No, `*s1` is not assigned the value of `*s2`. In `*s1 = *s2`, `*s1` is assigned the result of converting `*s2` to the type of `*s1`. For example, `int *s1 = (int [4]) { 0 }; float *s2 = (float []) { 2, 1, .5, 0 }; for (; *s1 = *s2; s1++, s2++) ; printf("%g", *s2);` prints “0.5”.

Comment: @EricPostpischil No: https://ideone.com/CKO8fy MINGW the same results. Two zeroes!! You have done something wrong

Comment: @EricPostpischil and https://onlinegdb.com/HJKE6T0-E

Comment: @P__J__: That is not the code I provided. The code in my comment prints “0.5”.

Comment: @EricPostpischil (int)(0.5) == 0

Comment: @P__J__: Yes, and then `*s1` is zero but `*s2` is not, so the assertion that the loop ends “when `*s2 == 0`” is false. As I wrote, a correct assertion is that the loop ends when `*s1` is zero after the assignment.

Comment: no because in the sense of this assignmet *s2 == 0 as int.

Comment: Ok except when the is floating point type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both codes copy the memory block referenced by the s2 into the the memory block referenced by the s1 until *s2 is not zero.

They are the same as your condition is the assignment.

the `{*s1=*s2;}` will be optimized out by most compilers.

for example if the pointers are `char *`

```
int main()
{
  for ( ; *s1 = *s2; s1++, s2++ ) { ;}
  for ( ; *s3 = *s4; s3++, s4++ ) {*s3=*s4;} 
}
```

The code is (-O3, -O2, -O1)

```
main:
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR ds:0
        test    al, al
        je      .L2
        mov     eax, 1
.L3:
        movzx   edx, BYTE PTR [rax]
        add     rax, 1
        test    dl, dl
        jne     .L3
.L2:
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR ds:0
        test    al, al
        je      .L4
        mov     eax, 1
.L5:
        movzx   edx, BYTE PTR [rax]
        add     rax, 1
        test    dl, dl
        jne     .L5
.L4:
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

Both loops are exactly the same

Comment: "Until `*s2` is not zero"?  Are you sure you wanted the "not" in that?  Or have I got myself knotted up?

Answer (score 4):

The second clause of the loop will evaluate to the value of the assignment and then use this value to determine whether to continue looping, so both loops will copy `s2` to `s1` until `*s1 == 0`. If `s1` and `s2` are the same type of pointer, then this occurs when `*s2 == 0`. If they are not the same type, then this is tricky code that is quite possibly incorrect.

The second loop contains an entirely redundant body, since it just repeats what the second clause of the loop does already.

Answer (score 1):

If `s1` and `s2` are of type `char*`, then the code implements a `strcpy`. The end-condition of a `strcpy` is "stop after having assigned the `'\0'`-string termination character.

So a third version would be...

```
for ( ; ; s1++, s2++ ) {
   *s1=*s2;
   if (!*s1) {
      break;
   }
}
```

Now let's dive into the meaning of an assignment like `*s1 = *s2`, which does actually two things: (1) it assigns `*s2` to `*s1`, and (2) the expression result is the value of `*s1` *after* the assignment;

In `for ( ; *s1 = *s2; s1++, s2++ ) { ;}`, where `*s1 = *s2` is used in the loop-end-condition, two things happen (1) the assignment and (2) the check if `'\0'` got assigned (in which case the loop ends).

In `for ( ; *s1 = *s2; s1++, s2++ ) {*s1=*s2;}`, the loop's body is simply superfluous; the assignment has already taken place when evaluating the "condition".

BTW: you could also write it as `while((*s1++=*s2++));`...

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to use == in the loop condition? Regardless,

Right now it performs an assignment - the result of the expression is the assigned value and is “true” until the value is 0.

Since the assignment is done in the loop condition, at the top of each loop, the assignment inside the loop is redundant as the same assignment has already occurred before the loop body executes.

Comment: I speculate that the OP found this code somewhere and is trying to understand it.

Comment: The check is performed at the end of the loop, so it is the assignment in the check that is redundant, not the assignment in the loop.